# How can I remove the hover delay in jQuery Mobile?

Tags: jquery, performance, jquery-mobile

I'm making a website with jQuery Mobile. When I hover over a button, it changes its class (and by extension, its color), but it feels like it takes half a second or so to do so. Is there a way to reduce this delay?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can override `hoverDelay` without modifying jQuery Mobile js library. To change defaults (global settings), you need to listen to `mobileinit` and do your changes.

Note that the below code should be placed in head after jQuery core and before jQuery Mobile libraries.

```
<script src="jquery.js"></script>
<script>
   $(document).on("mobileinit", function () {
      $.mobile.buttonMarkup.hoverDelay = 0;
   });
</script>
<script src="jquery-mobile.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

I found it. You have to change `buttonMarkup:{hoverDelay:200}` to `buttonMarkup:{hoverDelay:0}` in the jquery.js file.