# Cordova Crosswalk with JQM buttons don't render correctly down / active states

Tags: android, jquery-mobile, cordova, crosswalk-runtime

Just migrated my Cordova project to Cordova Crosswalk. Performance of the chromium engine is very nice and responsive, but there is a problem with most button states in JQM. This problem occurs even in arm and x86 cw compilation. I tryed different tags (button, input and a) and different data-attributes.

Behavior:
After press a form button or any button in a popup window, the button remains without down/active state. Hover state is working after the configured hover delay. Also "blank" buttons without form submission or popup call are working. The tap (even vclick,vmousedown,touchend) events would be fired correctly.

As example, this button works (Calls a option popup menu):

```
<li>
    <select id="language" name="language" data-native-menu="false" data-theme="b" data-overlay-theme="a">
        <option value="en">English</option>
        <option value="de">Deutsch</option>
    </select>
</li>
```

This button calls a popup and remains inactive.

```
<li>
    <button type="button" id="register" name="register" data-theme="b">New Account</button>
</li>
```

Any idea what could prevent the system from rendering the down state correctly?

Comment: the button becomes blue? or is the hover effect?

Comment: only hover effect with preferred $.mobile.buttonMarkup.hoverDelay

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/26962774/1771795

Comment: Thank you but hover is working and i already tryed hoverDelay = 0; The **active** and **down** states wouldn't refreshed. This must be chromium / crosswalk specific because normal cordova jqm app works like a charm.

Comment: another possibility, if you dont want the active button class, using `mobileinit` also `$.mobile.activeBtnClass = "";`.

Comment: Tryed this before but no luck. Same behavior.

Comment: then I assume it's not a problem related to jQM.